# using one public function inside another public function

Tags: php

The title may not make sense, not sure how to word it. Anyways, i'm practicing curl and OOP at the same time here with the riot games API. the API is kind of set up dumb where some info you want to request requires input that you wouldn't know off hand, so it requires another separate call to get the required info first.

```
class league
{
    const URL = 'http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.1/';
    const URL_2 = 'http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.1/';
    const KEY = 'key';

    public function summonerByName($summoner_name)
    {
        $request = 'summoner/by-name/' . $summoner_name . '?api_key =' . self::KEY;
        return $this->fetch($request);
    }

    public function recentGamesByName($summoner_name)
    {
        //need to make two calls for this since you cant get recent games by name in the api

        $id = summonerByName($summoner_name);

        //now get recent games
        $request = 'game/by-summoner/' . $id->id . '/recent';
        return $this->fetch($request);
    }   


    private function fetch($request)
    {
        $url = self::URL . $request . '?api_key=' . self::KEY;
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($data);
    }
}
```

this is returning `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  summonerbyname()`

if i use all this extra code below in the `public function recentGamesByName()` instead of `$id = summonerByName()` it works fine, but it seems unnecessary, and i want to replace that with just the function.

```
$grg = self::URL . 'summoner/by-name/' . $summoner_name . '?api_key=' . self::KEY;
$placeholder = curl_init($grg);
curl_setopt($placeholder, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ph_result = curl_exec($placeholder);
curl_close($placeholder);
$ph_result = json_decode($ph_result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$id = $this->summonerByName($summoner_name);`

You may want to read up on OOP.

Comment: i switched it to `$id = $this->summonerByName($summoner_name);`. now `$id->id` is nothing at all. in fact `var_dump($id)` is nothing at all.

Comment: nevermind thats just an issue with the summonerByName funciton, but this is where i was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to remember about OOP. When you're INSIDE the class and need to call another function, you use the the special $this variable.

So you would use:

```
$someVariable = $this->summonerByName($summoner_name);
```

to get the results from that function.

If you're OUTSIDE the class and need to access that function, then you need to assign the entire class to a variable like so:

```
$league = new league();
```

and then you can access any function within the class using that variable.

So you could do...

```
$someVariable = $league->summonerByName($summoner_name);
```

if you had already assigned the class to a variable name $league. By the way, that $league variable? It's called an object. Thus Object Oriented Programming. Objects are kinda like arrays, but use a different syntax. You can print_r an object just like you can print_r an array. When accessing an object's variable you use the $objectName->variableName syntax instead of $arrayName['variablename'] syntax that you use in arrays.

Comment: i had most of this figured out. was just confused by the `$this` usage. i've always just used arrays and never saw the point to objects in most cases. trying to understand objects now ha